# Unable to locate by element by class name using Selenium (Python)

Tags: python, html, selenium

I'm trying to locate a specific HTML element via class name but it's not finding anything. I've looked into it for a while but I'm unable to identify the issue

HTML snippet: [div's class name is fl-l score](https://i.stack.imgur.com/araJk.png)

My Python Code:

```
# Throws Timeout Exception because element unable to be located.
WebDriverWait(self.driver, 5).until(ec.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "fl-l score")))
score_block = self.driver.find_element_by_class_name("fl-l score")
```

I should also note that I tried finding it using XPath, which worked, but it's not a viable solution because the website is dynamic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of finding element by class name, you can change the locator by css selector for multiple class names:

```
WebDriverWait(self.driver, 5).until(ec.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".fl-l.score")))
score_block = self.driver.find_element_by_css_selector(".fl-l.score")
```

The above code hits the page twice, to be more efficient you should compress it into one line, like so:

```
score_block = WebDriverWait(self.driver, 5).until(ec.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".fl-l.score")))
```

Answer (score 0):

In Selenium we do not have support for **multiple class name**, so basically we are left with only `css` and `xpath` in this **kinda** situation.

Since **xpath is not viable solution** in your case. try `css`.

You can combine multiple classes by removing the `spaces` in between, and simply putting `.` in that place.

Also, `WebdriverWait` will always return a common exception, and it's hard to figure out what exactly went wrong, so try using `driver.find_element` in case you want to have the proper error stack trace.

But for just that matter you should not remove `WebdriverWait`.

Try this :

```
score_block = self.driver.find_element_by_class_name("div.fl-l.score")
```

should work for you. if it works then replace with `WebDriverWait`