# Unable to locate element by class name using selenium via Python. Why so?

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I wrote the following code in order to scrape the text of the element `<h3 class="h4 mb-10">Total nodes: 1,587</h3>`
from https://blockchair.com/dogecoin/nodes.

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions

path = "/usr/local/bin/chromedriver"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(path)

driver.get("https://blockchair.com/dogecoin/nodes")


def scraping_fnd():
    try:
        #nodes = driver.find_element_by_class_name("h4 mb-10")
#NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":".h4 mb-10"}. There are 3 elements pf this class
        #nodes = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(expected_conditions.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "h4 mb-10")))#selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message: 
        nodes = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(expected_conditions.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".h4 mb-10")))#selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message: 

        nodes = nodes.text
        print(nodes)
        

    finally: 
        driver.quit()#Closes the tab even when return is executed 
   
    
scraping_fnd()
```

I'm aware that there are perhaps [less bloated options](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/) than **selenium** to scrape the target in question, yet the said code is just a snippet,
a part of a more extensive script that relies on **selenium** for its other tasks. Thus let us limit the scope of the answers to **selenium**
only.

Although there are three elements of the class `"h4 mb-10"` on the page, I am unable to locate the element. When I call `driver.find_element_by_class_name("h4 mb-10")`, I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./protocols.py", line 34, in <module>
    scraping_fnd()
  File "./protocols.py", line 20, in scraping_fnd
    nodes = driver.find_element_by_class_name("h4 mb-10")#(f"//span[@title = \"{name}\"]")
  File "/home/jerzy/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 564, in find_element_by_class_name
    return self.find_element(by=By.CLASS_NAME, value=name)
  File "/home/jerzy/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 976, in find_element
    return self.execute(Command.FIND_ELEMENT, {
  File "/home/jerzy/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/home/jerzy/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":".h4 mb-10"}
  (Session info: chrome=90.0.4430.212)
 XP
```

[Applying waits](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html#waits), currently commented out in the snippet, was to no avail. I came across [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68978806/unable-to-locate-by-element-by-class-name-using-selenium-python/68978904#68978904) and so I tried calling `WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(expected_conditions.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".h4 mb-10")))`.
I got :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./protocols.py", line 33, in <module>
    scraping_fnd()
  File "./protocols.py", line 23, in scraping_fnd
    nodes = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(expected_conditions.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".h4 mb-10")))#selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message: 
  File "/home/jerzy/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/support/wait.py", line 80, in until
    raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message:
```

I have no clue what am I doing wrong. Is it doable to scrape the target with **selenium** without using Xpaths?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with this `xpath`. Find all the elements with this `xpath` and with indexing extract the required Text.

```
//div[@class='nodes_chain']/div[1]/h3 # for "Total nodes" option
//div[@class='nodes_chain']//h3 # for all the option.
```

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="path to chromedriver.exe")
driver.maximize_window()
driver.implicitly_wait(10)

driver.get("https://blockchair.com/dogecoin/nodes")

wait = WebDriverWait(driver,30)

option = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH,"//div[@class='nodes_chain']/div[1]/h3")))
print(option.text)

options = wait.until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH,"//div[@class='nodes_chain']//h3")))
# First option
print(options[0].text)

# All the options
for opt in options:
    print(opt.text)
```

```
Total nodes: 1,562 
Total nodes: 1,562
Total nodes: 1,562
Node versions
Block heights
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to go with css selector it would be
`.h4.mb-10`
You can go with class name
If either one  uniquely identifies the element or xpath
`//h3[@class="h4 mb-10"]`

Comment: `nodes = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//h3[@class=\"h4 mb-10\"]")
`
worked fine a couple of times. I called it outside of the function `scraping_fnd()` and commented out its execution.
But now the server refuses my connections.

Answer (score 1):

Try the below (Note that `selenium` is not involved in the solution)

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

r = requests.get('https://blockchair.com/dogecoin/nodes')
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')
lst = soup.find_all('h3',{"class": "h4 mb-10"})
lst = [h for h in lst if 'Total' in h.text]
print(lst[0].text)
```

output

```
Total nodes: 1,593
```